# Triple integrals, find the boundaries

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this triple integrals and before I can grind it down I have to find the boundaries. But I can't figure out how to find the boundaries for $x$

[image]

I know the boundaries are:

$0<x<2$

$x<y<(x+2)/2$

$0<z<(x^2+2y^2+1)$

But I don't understand why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundaries for $z$ are given: $0 \le z \le x^2+2y^2+1$.

for the other loock at the figure that represents the region in the plane $xy$ defined by the inequalities: $x+2\ge 2y \iff y\le \frac{x+2}{2}$ and $y\ge x$ and $x \ge 0$.
[image]

you can see that the limits for $x$ and $y$ are:

$0 \le x \le 2\quad \land \quad x \le y \le \frac{x+2}{2}$

So the integral is:
$$
\int_0^2\int_{x}^{\frac{x+2}{2}}\int _0^{x^2+2y^2+1}xdzdydx
$$